# Redirect to previous url after login in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I basically want to redirect to the previous url when a user has successfully logged in.

I redirect to the login page with the previous url such as `/login?redirect=/page1/page2`.

And I want when a user authenticates to be redirected back to that url.
I am using the `auth-module` here: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/

How I login the user.

```
methods: {
    async submit() {
      await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: this.form
      })
    }
}
```

The only thing that I could found in the docs is this: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/options#redirect

which however only redirects to a specific page instead of the previous page in the query.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You Can Do This

```
  this.$router.back()
```

And its go back to the last route.

Programmatic Navigation | Vue Router
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Thanks.

Comment: what if I wanna keep going to the previous page, not go back.  but go forward.

Comment: If i was on facebook for example first this would make me leave my website.. its not a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a fairly detailed discussion [in github](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/134) about Nuxt having an issue with a redirect when you are hitting a protected page directly.  The redirect goes to the default page redirect rather than the previously hit page.  The correct behavior should be to store the `redirect` and then proceed to it after authentication (login) with correct credentials.

3 days ago (Apr 14, 2019), [MathiasCiarlo](https://github.com/MathiasCiarlo) submitted a [PR](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/pull/333) on the `auth-module` repo to fix this.  The base reason why the redirect was "lost" has to do with the state of the redirect value not being allowed to be set as a cookie in SSR mode.  His code impacts the `storage.js` file, in particular the `setCookie()` method.  I've included that changed method here just for reference.

```
setCookie (key, value, options = {}) {
    if (!this.options.cookie) {
      return
    }

    const _key = this.options.cookie.prefix + key

    const _options = Object.assign({}, this.options.cookie.options, options)

    if (isUnset(value)) {
      Cookies.remove(_key, _options)
    } else {

      // Support server set cookies
      if (process.server) {
        this.ctx.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [_key + '=' + value])
      } else {
        Cookies.set(_key, value, _options)
      }
    }

    return value
  }
```

I've personally just altered my npm myself, but you could probably fork the repo and use that forked npm for the time being.  Or you could wait until the PR is merged into the mainline of the `auth-module` repo.